# Code with htmlentities not work properly

Tags: php, web

I start to learn php and create a code to learn how to use the `GET/POST` in php code.
So I heard an unsafe code can be executed through the input, so I create a checker using the 
`htmlentities()` function.

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['pwd']) or isset($_GET['firstname'], $_GET['lastname'], $_GET['pwd'])) {
    txt_check();
    $fname = $_GET['firstname'];
    $lname = $_GET['lastname'];
    $pwd = $_GET['pwd'];
    if ($fname == 'Or' and $lname == 'Halimi' and $pwd == 'password') {
        print 'Welcome master';
    } else {
        print 'You are not my master!';
    }
    echo format('<br/> <br/> {} {}', array($fname, $lname));  # like format in python
}

function txt_check() {
    foreach ($_GET as $name => $string) {
        $_GET[$name] = htmlentities($_GET[$name], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
    foreach ($_POST as $name => $string) {
        $_POST[$name] = htmlentities($_POST[$name], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is my function `txt_check()` not working,
but when I put `echo htmlentities($fname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') #fname=<script>` i get `&lt;script&gt;` at the end of the code.
Maybe I can't edit `$_GET`? I come from python so I don't know if `$_GET` is special in someway.

**Edit:**

I want to understand if i can change the global `$_GET\$_POST` like I did and if its good to doing so' because i don't know if the code inside `txt_check()` working for me.
If not, there is a better way to protect the input I get? Because i want to make a standard level of protecting, even if i dont even know the most risks that's hanging out there.

And why `htmlentities()` its not so good for this case? I use basic tutorial about php security to make it.

Comment: Converting `<script>` to `&lt;script&gt;` is the expected behaviour of `htmlentities`.

Comment: Don't use `htmlentities` unless you have a good reason to do so. Use `htmlspecialchars()` instead and also look up the arguments of the function.

Comment: You can edit `$_GET` by the way, though you usually probably shouldn't.

Comment: Also I agree with @MichaelBerkowski changing the superglobals like that will result in a WTF later. Use it like it is immutable.

Comment: Scrub the HTML tags out of the inputs you need to scrub, especially script and style, but most security issues arise from SQL injections where people put the $_GET and $_POST values directly into their queries. Do not take the entire superglobal and mess around with it.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra `most security issues arise from SQL injections` I won't forget XSS, that's what escaping html is for

Comment: @DamienPirsy You're right, I hsould have called that out explicitly, it's what I was hoping I was inferred by calling out script and style tags. Often times your more basic tags are allowed, usually for formatting. I'd strip out iframes too to be honest, and flash objects...maybe some others?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra By scrub do you mean strip? If yes: why would I care if somebody wants to call him/herself `' or 1 = 1;--\r\nHeader: Injection<script>alert('PeeHaa');</script>`?

Comment: @PeeHaa scrub as in clean it up

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to remove HTML tags, i would recommend you to use the `strip_tags`...not the `htmlentities`.

```
<?php
$mytext = "hello<br><script>alert('everybody');</script>";
$allow  = "<br>";
echo strip_tags($mytext,$allow);
?>
```

That will remove only the `script` tag.